# Payment and billing plan in one transaction

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

This is my first time using the PayPal API so go easy on me.

The case I am trying to handle is as follows:
My customers can purchase software licenses that can either be one time payments, or yearly payments.
They can multiple products to the cart, and each product can have either one of the pricing plans mentioned above.

If I understand correctly, "payments" in the API handle one time transactions, and "billing plans" are used for recurring payments.

Is it possible to processes both in one call to the API? If not, is there a different way to achieve this?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not one API call, but you can do it in one checkout flow with multiple API calls.

For PayPal wallet payments (logging in to PayPal and paying) I would recommend using [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) w/ [Recurring Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/).

With that you would be using SetExpressCheckout, GetExpressCheckoutDetails, and then either DoExpressCheckoutPayment, CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile, or a combination of both of those depending on the products in the card and whether they need one-time payment or recurring.

The CRPP call will allow you to setup a recurring profile and include an "initial payment" which would be charged when the profile is created.  This could be used as the one time payment if you want, and then you wouldn't need the DECP call.

Alternatively, you could use DECP to process the one time payment and then follow that up with CRPP to create the profile.  There are advantages and disadvantages to the different methods depending on your business needs.

For setting up profiles with direct credit cards you'll need PayPal Payments Pro.  In this case you would either use the same CRPP call mentioned above, but it would be used by itself and include the credit card details.  Or, depending on the version of Pro they put you on, which depends on the version of PayPal account you have, you might end up using PayFlow instead.

If you're working with PHP this [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) will make all of those API calls very quick and easy for you.

I know that's a pretty broad answer, but that's because it's a pretty broad question.  :)

Comment: thanks @andrewAngell for the broad answer, it is exactly what I was looking for! I just needed to know if this is at all possible before I start working, and your answer is very detailed and very helpful +1